# Calculate the product of two columns in an array then the sum C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

i have an array with columns where i need to do the SUM of the product of each row for 2 columns.

**Example:**

> 1 2 3 4 
>    1 2 3 4 
>    1 2 3 4 
>    1 2 3 4

**What i want to do is the following for col2 and col3:**

> Total = 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 = 24

**Below is my code for this operation:**

```
int product_col2Xcol3 = 0;
int sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = 0;

//Calculations of the SUM(Product) of col2 and col3
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
    {

        product_col2Xcol3 = matrix[j, col2] * matrix[j, col3];
        sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = sum_totalcol2Xcol3 + product_col2Xcol3 ;


    }

}
Console.WriteLine("Total is :" + 2*sum_totalcol2Xcol3 );
```

I am getting a result but the answer is wrong its a very big number. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What does the `for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)` do? You're calculating the `matrix[j, col2] * matrix[j, col3]` *  `r` times.

Comment: this seems to be the problem it is doing * r at the end this is why i am getting this huge number ... how to deal with it ?

Comment: why you are doing *r ,As per your example it not needed, and you were doing extra looping that why you was getting huge number.

Comment: @Johnny Please roll back your edit and post the code that was before. Right now this post has an accepted answer without a question. This will help nobody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) do? You're calculating the matrix[j, col2] * matrix[j, col3] * r times

```
int product_col2Xcol3 = 0;
int sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = 0;

//Calculations of the SUM(Product) of col2 and col3
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    product_col2Xcol3 = matrix[row, col2] * matrix[row, col3];
    sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = sum_totalcol2Xcol3 + product_col2Xcol3 ;
}

// why 2* ?????? think it shouldn't be there.
Console.WriteLine("Total is :" + 2*sum_totalcol2Xcol3 );
```

or

```
int sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    sum_totalcol2Xcol3 += matrix[row, col2] * matrix[row, col3];
}
Console.WriteLine("Total is :" + sum_totalcol2Xcol3 );
```

Comment: Saw it, You might noticed it was a typo?

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the j part ! works like a charm ty

Answer (score 2):

```
  int[,] matrix={
                    {1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {1, 2, 3, 4}
                };


  int product_col2Xcol3 = 0;
  int sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = 0;

  // if you precisely want the column 1 and 2 of each row then do as below:
  for (int row = 0; row <matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
  {

      product_col2Xcol3 = matrix[row, 1] * matrix[row, 2];
      sum_totalcol2Xcol3 += product_col2Xcol3;

  }
  Console.WriteLine("Total is :" + sum_totalcol2Xcol3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int product_col2Xcol3 = 0;
int sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = 0;

//Calculations of the SUM(Product) of col2 and col3
for (int row = 0; row < number_of_rows; row++)
{

     product_col2Xcol3 = matrix[row, col2] * matrix[row, col3];
     sum_totalcol2Xcol3 = sum_totalcol2Xcol3 + product_col2Xcol3 ;

}
Console.WriteLine("Total is :" + sum_totalcol2Xcol3 );
```